# animated SVG + cross browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg

I'm having trouble with an animated SVG I created using http://lazylinepainter.info/

On Chrome it works perfectly.  However on Safari, Firefox and iOS the animation shows the end points of the crosses as dots.  Here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ric0c/aqn6zkf4/1/

and here's my svg code:

```
    var pathObj2 = {
        "strategy": {
            "strokepath": [
                {
                    "path": "  M22.5,59.6c10.8,0,19.5,8.7,19.5,19.5s-8.7,19.5-19.5,19.5S3,89.8,3,79.1c0-10.7,8.7-19.4,19.4-19.5",
                    "duration": 600
                },
                {
                    "path": "  M177.4,3c10.8,0,19.5,8.7,19.5,19.5S188.2,42,177.4,42s-19.5-8.7-19.5-19.5c0-10.7,8.7-19.4,19.4-19.5",
                    "duration": 600
                },
                {
                    "path": "  M113.5,155.6c10.8,0,19.5,8.7,19.5,19.5c0,10.8-8.7,19.5-19.5,19.5S94,185.8,94,175.1c0-10.7,8.7-19.4,19.4-19.5",
                    "duration": 600
                },
                {
                    "path": "  M200.1,57.1c10.8,12.5,17.3,28.8,17.3,46.6c0,39.4-31.9,71.3-71.3,71.3",
                    "duration": 600
                },
                {
                    "path": "M 141.2 73.7 L 166.2 98.7",
                    "duration": 600
                },
                {
                    "path": "M 166.2 73.7 L 141.2 98.7",
                    "duration": 600
                },
                {
                    "path": "M 78.2 116.1 L 103.2 141.1",
                    "duration": 600
                },
                {
                    "path": "M 103.2 116.1 L 78.2 141.1",
                    "duration": 600
                },
                {
                    "path": "M 235.2 142.1 L 260.2 167.1",
                    "duration": 600
                },
                {
                    "path": "M 260.2 142.1 L 235.2 167.1",
                    "duration": 600
                },
                {
                    "path": "M   196.1,76.7 200.1,57.1 219.7,61.1 L  196.1,76.7 200.1,57.1 219.7,61.1 ",
                    "duration": 600
                }
            ],
            "dimensions": {
                "width": 264,
                "height": 198
            }
        }
    }; 

    $('#strategy').lazylinepainter({
        "svgData": pathObj2,
        "strokeWidth": 6,
        "strokeColor": "#FFFFFF",
        'onComplete' : function(){
            setTimeout(function() { 
                    $('#strategy').lazylinepainter('erase');
                    $('#strategy').lazylinepainter('paint');
                }, 5000);
            }
    }).lazylinepainter('paint');


    var state = 'paint';
    $('#strategy').lazylinepainter(state);
```

Any help on how to eliminate those dots would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in FF (IMO anyway).  It should not be drawing the line endcaps if the line ends exactly at a dash endpoint.

One quick fix is to change your stroke-caps to "butt".

```
'strokeCap': 'butt',
```

This works on Firefox at least.  I can't test whether this works on Safari.

If you want to keep the round caps, then a workaround is to make sure that the lines don't start and end exactly on a dasharray endpoint.  Change these two lines in the `paint()` function.

```
path.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + (length+2);
path.style.strokeDashoffset = (length+1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aqn6zkf4/3/

Comment: I have reported this on Bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1169258

Comment: thanks for that, @paul-lebeau.  Appreciate the fix, that worked great.